# Trim string's suffix or extension?

Tags: string, go

For example, I have a string, consists of "sample.zip". How do I remove the ".zip" extension using strings package or other else?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**Edit: Go has moved on. Please see [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21538822/83264).**

Use [path/filepath.Ext](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Ext) to get the extension. You can then use the length of the extension to retrieve the substring minus the extension.

```
var filename = "hello.blah"
var extension = filepath.Ext(filename)
var name = filename[0:len(filename)-len(extension)]
```

Alternatively you could use [strings.LastIndex](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#example_LastIndex) to find the last period (.) but this may be a little more fragile in that there will be edge cases (e.g. no extension) that `filepath.Ext` handles that you may need to code for explicitly, or if Go were to be run on a theoretical O/S that uses a extension delimiter other than the period.

Comment: strings.TrimSuffix, underneath, does the same array math/indices :)

Comment: @rogerdpack, yes people should use Keith's answer. `TrimSuffix` didn't exist in Go when I wrote this answer (it was [added in Go 1.1 in February 2013](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/diff?spec=svnc7353c98694b135ba941cea93b01e5c0e6a4dd55&old=c0f7c53dcfce43f4921cce7bb2ef7800c752bf4c&r=c7353c98694b135ba941cea93b01e5c0e6a4dd55&format=unidiff&path=%2Fsrc%2Fpkg%2Fstrings%2Fstrings.go)).

Comment: `filepath.Ext(filename)` did not work for me, I needed to use `path.Ext(filename)` instead. Thanks tho.

Comment: `strings.TrimSuffix` would make an unnecessary/redundant comparison compared to pure string slicing. Not a big deal in terms of  performance but there is a tiny difference and both solutions are easy to understand.

Answer (score 279):

Try:

```
basename := "hello.blah"
name := strings.TrimSuffix(basename, filepath.Ext(basename))
```

TrimSuffix basically tells it to strip off the trailing string which is the extension with a dot.

[strings#TrimSuffix](//golang.org/pkg/strings#TrimSuffix)

Comment: Note that `filepath.Ext("test.tar.gz")` returns `.gz` which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: If you want the filename in case of multiple extensions (e.g. `tar.gz`) use `strings.Split` with dot separator
https://play.golang.com/p/nyhC6-YJ7PE

Comment: `Ext` is non reliable method, it also includes parameter. given `hello.blah?foo=bar` , it would return `.blah?foo=bar`

Comment: @TomSawyer You should always use the `net/url` package to parse your URL before doing anything with the path. You likely also want to use `path.Ext` rather than `filepath.Ext`, as it's a path received over HTTP rather than one designed for use with the filesystem.

Comment: in term of getting ext from string , it simply doesn't work. and this is not the good answer. i have to write my own method to solve it. using above code gives you error

Comment: The answer by [Paul Ruane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027975/5728991) avoids an unnecessary string comparison in strings.TrimSuffix.

Answer (score 2):

This is just one line more performant. Here it is:

```
filename := strings.Split(file.Filename, ".")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This way works too:

```
var filename = "hello.blah"
var extension = filepath.Ext(filename)
var name = TrimRight(filename, extension)
```

but maybe Paul Ruane's method is more efficient?

Comment: I think TrimRight here removes a "cutset" (i.e. character set) from the end, which may not be what you want here: http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRight (see also TrimSuffix)

Answer (score 1):

I am using go1.14.1, `filepath.Ext` did not work for me, `path.Ext` works fine for me

```
var fileName = "hello.go"
fileExtension := path.Ext(fileName)
n := strings.LastIndex(fileName, fileExtension)
fmt.Println(fileName[:n])
```

Playground: [https://play.golang.org/p/md3wAq_obNc](https://play.golang.org/p/cK6cNQM0CP6)

Documnetation: https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Ext

Answer (score 1):

Here is example that does not require `path` or `path/filepath`:

```
func BaseName(s string) string {
   n := strings.LastIndexByte(s, '.')
   if n == -1 { return s }
   return s[:n]
}
```

and it seems to be faster than `TrimSuffix` as well:

```
PS C:\> go test -bench .
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkTrimFile-12            166413693                7.25 ns/op
BenchmarkTrimPath-12            182020058                6.56 ns/op
BenchmarkLast-12                367962712                3.28 ns/op
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#LastIndexByte

Answer (score -1):

Summary, including the case of multiple extension names <sup>abc.tar.gz</sup> and performance comparison.

temp_test.go

```golang
package _test
import ("fmt";"path/filepath";"strings";"testing";)
func TestGetBasenameWithoutExt(t *testing.T) {
    p1 := "abc.txt"
    p2 := "abc.tar.gz" // filepath.Ext(p2) return `.gz`
    for idx, d := range []struct {
        actual   interface{}
        expected interface{}
    }{
        {fmt.Sprint(p1[:len(p1)-len(filepath.Ext(p1))]), "abc"},
        {fmt.Sprint(strings.TrimSuffix(p1, filepath.Ext(p1))), "abc"},
        {fmt.Sprint(strings.TrimSuffix(p2, filepath.Ext(p2))), "abc.tar"},
        {fmt.Sprint(p2[:len(p2)-len(filepath.Ext(p2))]), "abc.tar"},
        {fmt.Sprint(p2[:len(p2)-len(".tar.gz")]), "abc"},
    } {
        if d.actual != d.expected {
            t.Fatalf("[Error] case: %d", idx)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkGetPureBasenameBySlice(b *testing.B) {
    filename := "abc.txt"
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = filename[:len(filename)-len(filepath.Ext(filename))]
    }
}

func BenchmarkGetPureBasenameByTrimSuffix(b *testing.B) {
    filename := "abc.txt"
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = strings.TrimSuffix(filename, filepath.Ext(filename))
    }
}
```

run cmd: `go test temp_test.go -v -bench="^BenchmarkGetPureBasename" -run=TestGetBasenameWithoutExt`

output

```
=== RUN   TestGetBasenameWithoutExt
--- PASS: TestGetBasenameWithoutExt (0.00s)
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
BenchmarkGetPureBasenameBySlice
BenchmarkGetPureBasenameBySlice-8               356602328                3.125 ns/op
BenchmarkGetPureBasenameByTrimSuffix
BenchmarkGetPureBasenameByTrimSuffix-8          224211643                5.359 ns/op
PASS
```